# Reading in .txt files to Apple's Numbers

Tags: applescript

I have a list of .txt files all in the same directory with the name "w_i.txt" where i runs from 1 to n. Each of these files contains a single number (non integer). I want to be able to read in the value from each of these files into a column in Apple's Numbers. I want w_1.txt in row 1 and w_n.txt's value in row n of that column. Should I use Applescript for this and if so what code would be required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would tackle this as a shell script, rather than applescript.

The following script will iterate over your set of files in numerical order, and produce plain text output.  You can redirect this to a text file.  I don't have access to Apple's Numbers, but I'd be very surprised if you can't import data from a plain text file.

I have hard-coded the max file index as 5.  You'll want to change that.

If there are any files missing, a 0 will be output on that line instead.  You could change that to a blank line as required.

Also I don't know if your files end in newlines or not, so the cat/read/echo line is one way to just get the first token of the line and not worry about any following whitespace.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..5} ; do
    if [ -e w_$i.txt ] ; then
        cat w_$i.txt | { IFS="" read -r n ; echo -e "$n" ; }
    else
        echo 0
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If all files end with newlines, you could just use cat:

```
cd ~/Documents/some\ folder; cat w_*.txt | pbcopy
```

This works even if the files don't end with newlines and sorts w_2.txt before w_11.txt:

```
sed -n p $(ls w_*.txt | sort -n)
```